# Python 2 issues appending nested list item to new list "int object is unsubscriptable"

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains a subset of lists, each subset list is 5 elements, the 5th element is an int/datetime object.  when I loop such that:

```
for items in baseList:
    newList.append(items[4])
```

example of one of the baseList:

```
baseList = [[string1, string2, string3, string4, datetimeobj],[string1, string2, string3, string4, datetimeobj],intofListcount]
```

if I try to print

```
items[4]
```

it prints them and then errors out with the same traceback after it prints them all "int type is unsubscriptable".  I'm not sure why it thinks I'm trying to slice the int as though it were a string or list type?

Comment: Obviously, `intofListcount` is an integer. And `for items in baseList:` loops over _all of the `baseList`'s contents_, including that integer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through `baseList` and it works - until you get to `intofListcount` - according to the error, this is an integer, but you are trying to treat it like a list by subscripting it.

Try this:

```
for items in baseList:
    if isinstance(items, list) and len(items) > 4:
        newList.append(items[4])
```

This will check that `items` is a list AND that it has at least 5 elements, thereby skipping the final `intofListcount`, or any other non lists or lists that don't have a item at index `[4]`.

Comment: I also found that I forgot I wasn't printing out one of the list elements that I wanted to remain stored but not in the output, so I was accidentally selected intoflistcount instead of the final element in the nested list :\

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the fact that `baseList` is not homogenous - as in not every item in the list has the same structure.

Specifically, in the example you gave:

```
baseList = [[string1, string2, string3, string4, datetimeobj],
            [string1, string2, string3, string4, datetimeobj],
            intofListcount
           ]
```

the entry at `baseList[2]` is not another list - or anything else that you can subscript (i.e. not an iterable such as a `list` or `tuple`).

You need to guard the subscripting with some checks, such as `if isinstance(items, list)`

And you could simply replace your loop with a comprehension

```
newList = [ items[4] for items in baseList if isinstance(items,list) and len(items) >= 5]
```